# How to write a nested DL query

Tags: owl, protege, description-logic, dlquery

I want to write a nested DL query in Protege. I can run a simple query like:

> **Person and hasFather value PersonA**

It retrieves the name of all the Persons whose Father is PersonA. But I want that PersonA value should also be retrieved from some query like

> **Person and hasFather value (Person and hasSon value PersonB)**

It is showing syntax error in Protege. Please help me with the correct format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that

```
Person and hasFather value (Person and hasSon value PersonB)
```

is a syntax error is not that it's “nested”, but that `value` requires an *individual*, but `(Person and hasSon value PersonB)` is a *class*.  If you use

```
Person and hasFather some (Person and hasSon value PersonB)
```

instead, you should be all set.  This query asks for individuals that are people that have a father that is a person and has person B as a son.  That is, it's asking  for siblings of person B, i.e., other children of person B's father.

For instance, here's a query about the Simpson family where Bart and Lisa each have Homer as their father, and Homer has each of them as a child:

[image: simpsons query]

The data is:

```
@prefix :      <http://www.example.org/families#> .
@prefix rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix owl:   <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix xsd:   <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix families: <http://www.example.org/families#> .

<http://www.example.org/families>
        a       owl:Ontology .

families:Person  a  owl:Class .

families:hasFather  a  owl:ObjectProperty .

families:hasChild  a  owl:ObjectProperty .

families:Bart  a            owl:NamedIndividual , families:Person ;
        families:hasFather  families:Homer .

families:Lisa  a            owl:NamedIndividual , families:Person ;
        families:hasFather  families:Homer .

families:Homer  a          owl:NamedIndividual , families:Person ;
        families:hasChild  families:Bart , families:Lisa .

families:Milhouse  a  owl:NamedIndividual , families:Person .
```